# Airbnb housing gone electrifyingly bad

Tags: usa, accommodation, california, compensation, airbnb

I am staying at a place booked via Airbnb. Something happened and there is no electricity from Friday! The house-owner has provided a super noisy generator, which is inconsistent, meaning that it "randomly" supplies power to some parts of the house, so you cannot rely on it.

Is there any rule/law in SF, CA, USA to describe the compensation one should get from such kind a situation?

---

The owner owns the whole building. On the ground floor there is a restaurant. On the 1st floor there are the apartments. Something happened in the restaurant, which made the electricity go off, but she didn't give more details, she said "there was an emergency and the power went off".

Comment: @pnuts really? So I am paying that much money for a house I cannot even use? :/ That's worse than the US elections. What do you mean with "randomly"?

Comment: I updated @pnuts!

Comment: @pnuts it doesn't worth suing for it. I am only willing to settle that with her alone. The problem is that I have already paid, because if I didn't I wouldn't give a penny for these days...

Comment: I suspect either the restaurant has lost its license or has not paid its utility bill. Besides demanding a refund from AirBnB, I suggest you contact the power utility (PG&E) to find out what the situation is.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus the restaurant is closed, with a sign "We have technical difficulties, we will re-open as soon as possible...".

Comment: Restaurants don't make money when closed (and often not when open). I would call the utility; if power to an apartment house is shut off for nonpayment there may be special provisions. And if there really is something dangerous in the restaurant, a crew should investigate it. Number for utility is 1 (800) 743-5000.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus if it was that the restaurant was not paying its bill, then I don't think we should have PG&E already in the house. Moreover, the father of the owner shows up and tries to repair stuff, so it seems that there was something gone bad at the electrical system of the restaurant. My phone is Greek, so I cannot call...But thanks! ;)

Comment: If the electricity has been out for nearly a week and the owners actually cared about the problem, they'd have professional licensed electricians on site, not the father of the owner "trying" to fix it. It seems evident that they don't care, and you should contact AirBnB to find a new place to stay and get compensation. Out of curiosity, how long were you renting the AirBnB for (more than 30 days or less)?

Comment: I asked her about it and she said that there is an electrician that helps the father, but I haven't seen him. However, to be fair, I am not at home at morning..12 weeks @ZachLipton, I am only interested in compensation, since I am about to to Greece or Chile next week.

Comment: @gsamaras As I recall, you have a lot of rights in San Francisco if you're staying in a place for more than 30 days: you're treated as a tenant in a rented house, rather than a guest in a hotel.

Comment: @pnuts _Force majeur_ is an issue between the landlord and her insurer. The asker contracted the landlord to provide habitable accommodation and the landlord failed to do that.

Comment: @pnuts I have no more details than are in the question and the comments; I'd rather leave it to the asker to edit any of that into the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I feel the same way. I don't even care if the Dinosaurs attacked the electrical setup, I paid so much money...Thank you all!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Contact AirBnB support](https://www.airbnb.com/help/contact_us) directly, do not wait.

Ask them to help you move to another apartment. Also ask for compensation.

Anecdotal: 
There was a major water problem at an apartment my parents rented near Paris, with AirBnb.
They contacted support and were lucky to be moved to another apartment nearby, and they got some compensation.

Comment: I don't want to move, since I am leaving in a few days, but I would like to get the compensation, thanks Max! Ah Paris, hope the water was not as smelly as the water in that river they have there... :P

Comment: @gsamaras PG&E has a FB page where you can message and from which you might get a response https://www.facebook.com/pacificgasandelectric/

Comment: @gsamaras another avenue could be to contact the San Francisco Office of Short-Term Rental’s; the unit has to be on the Registry and, if there are problems, you might have leverage for compensation shorttermrentals@sfgov.org

Comment: @gsamaras; here's another link to pursue vis a vis warrant of habitability (https://www.sftu.org/repairs/)

Comment: Looks good @Dorothy, thanks for helping out! From the shorttermrentals, they told me to contact https://sf311.org/web/guest/mysf311.org#

Comment: Your best bet is AirBnB, not contacting the city. You're AirBnB's customer.

Comment: Agreed with @ZachLipton . However, if AirBnB doesn't take care of it quickly, then contacting the city is probably the next best bet.

Comment: There's a lot of tension between AirBnB and the city of San Francisco. If AirBnB don't sort it out, I imagine that the city council will be a solid ally.

Comment: @ZachLipton Although I have found in my many (bad) experiences dealing with Airbnb that you are AirBnB's customer when it suits them, but you have a contractual arrangement between guest and owner for which they are just agent, when that suits them instead. Their terms and conditions ran to 78 pages when I printed them to a PDF, meaning it's virtually impossible to figure out the true situation without hiring a lawyer. Plus the fact that you can be dealing with separate AirBnB companies in multiple jurisdictions, depending on what the issue is.

Comment: @ZachLipton With that said, I've found that in the case of guest disputes, they are generally efficient (sometimes unfairly so towards the owner) in issuing refunds.